# App android siempre vertical?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Quiero que mi APP solo se ejecute verticalmente pero no lo consigo, he implementado lo siguiente sin éxito.

Manifest:

```
< application
        ...
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Actividad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En su archivo `Mainfest.xml` encuentre las etiquetas de las actividades que desea bloquear en una rotación determinada.

**Necesita agregar a toda su actividad no solo para uno, es decir, establezca esto para todas sus actividades:**

```
<activity android:name=".SuActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Explicación:

> - `android:configChanges="orientation"` será responsable de los cambios de orientación.
> - `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` configura el modo de orientación predeterminado.

---

**Otra forma es:**

Usar `setRequestedOrientation()` como se muestra aquí:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```